# Не могу вернуть ArrayList из потока после парсинга

Tags: android, kotlin, потоки-данных, jsoup, асинхронность

У меня есть отдельный класс, метод в котором генерирует мне ArrayList. В нем обычный поток, а в потоке в try/catch парсится и наполняется инфой ArrayList. Дальше этот ArrayList нужно как-то вернуть из try/catch(с этим разобрался в принципе) и вернуть из потока(а вот с этим нет). Говорят юзать корутины, но там для меня та же проблема. Пока единственным решением видится... async task

```
val url: String = "https://ranobelib.ru/ranobe/"

    fun listMain(): ArrayList<String> {
        Thread {
            var listMain = ArrayList<String>()
            try {
                val document: Document = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 " +
                                "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"
                    )
                    .timeout(100000).get()
                val items: Elements = document.getElementsByClass("item")
                for (item in items) {
                    listMain.add(
                        BookData(
                            item.select("a").text(),
                            item.select("a").text(),
                            item.select("img").first().attr("src"),
                            item.select("a").first().attr("href")
                        ).toString()
                    )
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }.start()
        return listMain
    }
```

BookData:

```
data class BookData(
    var title: String,
    var info: String,
    var image_url: String,
    var book_url: String
)
```

Comment: У вас стандартная проблема непонимания асинхронности. То, как вы хотите написать код - не получится. Вы не можете написать метод, который синхронно вернёт результат асинхронной операции. Выход - метод не должен ничего возвращать. Но должен принимать колбэк, куда результат выдаст. Корутины, AsyncTask и прочее - всего лишь вариации описанного подхода. Просто смените логику программы, убрав возвращаемый тип у метода и передав в него колбэк

Comment: Мне говорили использовать колбэки, но я так и не понимаю как они работают. Прочитал уже 2 статьи про них и все равно не понимаю. Но с вашим ответом это непонимание уменьшилось

Comment: Вот тут рабочий пример с асинк таском. Я по идее должен что-то подобное сделать... https://github.com/XcyperX/RanobeParser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/ranobeparser/activity/MainActivity.java

Comment: Я попробую дать вам ссылку позже или даже код покажу. По ссылке вашей на github очень неправильный способ. Никогда так не делайте!

Comment: Ну так делал и не я. Хотя я начинал свой проект с форка того проекта, но задолбался фиксить мелкие баги

Comment: Мне подсказали как можно использовать корутины, завтра попробую и если получится, то выложу сюда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вот так.

MainActivity.OnCreate():

```
GlobalScope.launch(){
            var listMain = listMain()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val MainAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*> = MainAdapter(listMain)
                books_recycler.adapter = MainAdapter
            }
        }
```

Parser:

```
companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun listMain(): ArrayList<String> {
            var listMain = ArrayList<String>()
            try {
                val document: Document = Jsoup.connect("https://ranobelib.ru/ranobe/")
                    .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 " +
                                "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"
                    )
                    .timeout(100000).get()
                val items: Elements = document.getElementsByClass("item")
                for (item in items) {
                    listMain.add(
                        BookData(
                            item.select("a").text(),
                            item.select("a").text(),
                            item.select("img").first().attr("src"),
                            item.select("a").first().attr("href")
                        ).toString()
                    )
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return listMain
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Запрос в сеть должен происходить не на главном потоке, асинхронно. Засим нельзя написать код такого рода:

```
fun getDataFromNetwork() : Something { 
    /* Тут асинхронный код, который неизвестно сколько будет выполнятся
       и выполнится ли вообще успешно. 
       Вдруг сети нет или она пропадёт в процессе или сервер сломается */ 
}
```

Соответственно, вы не сможете этот метод использовать из главного потока так:

```
someView.showDataOnScreen(getDataFromNetwork())
```

Поступать надо иначе: только в тот момент, когда будет успешно завершён сетевой запрос - вызвать код, который полученные данные выведет на экран. Выглядеть это может примерно так:

```
fun getDataFromNetwork() {
    /* Тут асинхронный код, который неизвестно сколько будет выполнятся
       и выполнится ли вообще успешно. 
       Вдруг сети нет или она пропадёт в процессе или сервер сломается */ 
    showDataOnScreen(variableWithDataFromNetwork)
}

fun showDataOnScreen(variableWithDataFromNetwork: Something) {
    someView.showDataOnScreen(variableWithDataFromNetwork)
}
```

Важно запускать `showDataOnScreen()` на главном потоке. Сделать это можно по разному. Если этот метод в активити - то всё его содержимое вызывайте через `runOnUiThread()` метод активити.

Comment: Не подходит так как этот лист используется в ресайкле, а если точнее я им адаптер кормлю

Comment: Это вполне подходит) В ответе описано ровно то, что вы в итоге через корутины сделали. Просто детали реализации скрыты от вас тем как работают корутины